# "File not found error" while creating site collection using a template

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

getting `"file not found error"` while creating a site collection using template.

Template is created using visual studio 2010 ,using import SharePoint project solutions these are the steps that I followed for creating this template.
imported the wsp using visual studio and changed the scope of the feature 3 to "farm" and deployed the solution globally.

I am getting the file not found error while creating a new site collection from the central admin using this template.

can any one help me on this?

Comment: Could be some file like master page, page layout or any other resource could be missing? Try installing required WSPs again.

Comment: how you deployed the solution and how you trying to create site collection?

Comment: deployed from visual studio then ,deployed globally from central admin .

Comment: create new site collection from the central admin.application management>create new site collection.the new template can be selected under the option custom.select the template and click create.it is proccessing for few minutes after that error is coming like file not found .

Comment: how to find out the missing file? it is not mentioned in the uls log

Comment: some deployment conflicts are happening while deployment. could not delete some list or some thing that already exist in the server...is that the reason for this file not found error?

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it sounds like your custom master page may not
be accessible by SP. If you successfully create the site/collection
but you see the file not found error, SP can't render the page you're
after becaeuse it's missing the all important master page. Not totally
sure that's your issue, but it sure sounds like it.

Update your web.config StackTrace=TRUE you will see the real error of what file is missing.

Which master page is attached to the site template ?
Or in other way on the source site did you also modified the master page ?
make sure while you create a new site using that template it will be inherited from the source master page.

refer 
http://mm4sp.blogspot.com/2011/05/file-not-found-error-when-you-open.html

Also make sure if there is any custom feature used on source site it should be activated on the destination portal and then try to make site collection.

---

Or Try this solution: Go to Site settings of parent site -> under group Look and Feel, click on Master Page -> check on 3 checkboxes: Reset all subsites to inherit this Site Master Page setting Reset all subsites to inherit this system Master Page setting Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL

Click OK Check your sub site again.

Comment: i am not trying to create a sub site. iam trying to create a new site collection.

Comment: i have attached a custom master page to the template